# Finding good high-dimensional sphere coverings in Euclidean space

Tags: algorithms, lattices, computational-geometry, covering, sphere-packing

Suppose we want to cover the unit sphere $\mathcal{S}^{d-1} := \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d: \|\mathbf{x}\|_2 = 1\}$ with spherical caps $\mathcal{C}_{\mathbf{y}} := \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}^{d-1}: \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \rangle \geq \alpha\}$ for a given parameter $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. Each spherical cap roughly covers a fraction $(1 - \alpha^2)^{d/2}$ of the unit sphere, so $T = (1 - \alpha^2)^{-d/2}$ vectors sampled at random from the sphere would form a decent covering of the unit sphere. However, some areas would not be covered by such a set of random spherical caps, some areas would be covered several times, and it feels like there should be better ways to obtain better sphere packings than sampling vectors at random.

My problem is: given $\alpha$ (or $T$) and $d$, generate a better sphere covering code $C = \{\mathbf{y}_1, \mathbf{y}_2, \dots, \mathbf{y}_T\}$ than what you would get by sampling vectors at random from the sphere. At this point I am open to almost any time complexity for generating such a set (exponential in $d$ might even be ok), and also I'd welcome practical, heuristic tweaks to improve a given code $C$ to a better code $C' = f(C)$ by making small adjustments to the code.

---

Edit: to clarify, I am looking for coverings which should be sufficiently dense with the fewest number of vertices; I'd prefer an approximate covering which covers $99\%$ of the sphere with $T$ nodes which barely overlap, over a complete covering which for instance requires $2T$ nodes with a lot of overlap. In general I'd also prefer a randomized/heuristic algorithm which usually gives a good covering with a small number of vertices, over a deterministic/provable algorithm which always generates a good covering with a larger number of vertices: I do not care about provability, and the codes do not have to be perfect coverings.

Comment: Try a bathroom floor tiling algorithm: place one circle, then an overlapping circle near it, then one near that, and continue, keeping track of the boundary of the union.  When the boundary is gone, you are all done!  Gerhard "Mathematical Do It Yourself Tips" Paseman, 2016.06.14

Comment: @Gerhard How do you keep track of the boundary of a union of several spherical caps in high dimensions? I'm interested in dimensions in the range say between $50$ and $100$, and the boundary of a union of say $1000$ caps in those dimensions is not easy to describe.

Comment: I would use linked lists or a graph with coloring.  Let two vectors be considered adjacent if they are centers of circles which overlap. For each vector v, make a list of adjacent vectors which are part of the cover with v, and another list which are not in the cover but are also adjacent to v, and cover parts of the circle boundary of v not covered by anything in the first   list.  Use geometry on the first list to generate candidates for the second list.  Gerhard "Or Use Multidimensional Tracing Paper" Paseman, 2016.06.14.

Comment: @Gerhard Intuitively I expect your algorithm would generate very dense packings, rather than nice coverings. For a good covering, you don't expect any other centers to be very close to the boundary of one of the spherical caps. If each new center lies on the boundary of the previous ones, you'd need many more vectors to cover the sphere. (I think I've seen your algorithm mentioned in a packing paper for three dimensions.)

Comment: In choosing a new vector, I look for vectors adjacent to some existing vector already in the cover.  These vectors are not on the boundary.  I mention the boundary because such vectors have their circles intersect the boundary.  The new vector is not always near the boundary but should be less than a radius away.  Gerhard "Sort Of Like Social Networking" Paseman, 2016.06.14.

Comment: @Gerhard Is there any reason to believe this method would work better than sampling vectors at random? Did anyone ever test this construction for generating sphere *coverings* rather than sphere packings? Or is there some intuition why this would work well?

Comment: It depends on what you sample randomly.  Suppose you start your cover with a cap with center v, and choose d vectors to represent circles adjacent to (and covering the boundary of the circle surrounding) v.  You  can take this configuration and rotate it to adjacent spots to make a larger partial cover.  By clever replication, you can make this a locally optimal cover if the original template was locally optimal.  This is my intuition for why this would be computationally efficient.  Gerhard "Leaves Clever Replication To You" Paseman, 2016.06.16.

Comment: @Gerhard I agree that that could work locally, but once you start wrapping around the sphere you will intuitively start getting collisions; you want to put a point at both the nearby points $v$ and $v'$ (based on the adjacency to $w$ and $w'$) and they are too close to form a nice configuration. And since the "wrapping around" already starts at three or four adjacent configuration, I don't see how this would work nicely for the entire sphere. Note that I am generally more interested in partial coverings of $T$ vectors which cover say $90\%$ of the sphere than full coverings of $2T$ vectors.

Comment: That you are more interested in partial coverings than full covers is a detail which you should make clear in your post.  In that case, you may be able to use the locally optimal strategy more effectively by using an optimal covering with large caps (or large sections, e.g. triangles for an icosahedral partition), and then break it down by finding a nice partial cover for each section.  Gerhard "You Can Always Try Wedges" Paseman, 2016.06.17.